# Guardar datos en xlsx desde r

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy generando un historial de numero desde r a xlsx, pero no se como hacer un salto de linea para que cada momento que ingrese un numero nuevo se coloque debajo del ultimo.

```
write.table(round(i), file = " ",eol = " ",row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Esta linea escribe un numero únicamente y sobre escribe cada vez que coloco uno nuevo. Me podrían dar una idea de como realizar esto.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien el sentido de ir salvando línea a linea, normalmente partes de un `data.frame` u objeto similar y los salvas directamente. De todas formas, lo que buscas es ir agregando líneas a un archivo de texto, seguramente `csv` para luego leerlo desde el excel. Del código que has compartido te falta:

- indicar un nombre de archivo (`file = "foo.csv"`)
- Indicar un el salto de línea (`eol = "\n"`)
- Agregar el parámetro `append` para no sobreescribir el archivo:

Ejemplo:

```
i <- 1
write.table(round(i), file = "foo.csv", eol = "\n", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)

i <- 2
write.table(round(i), file = "foo.csv", eol = "\n", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)

i <- 3
write.table(round(i), file = "foo.csv", eol = "\n", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)

read.table(file = "foo.csv")

  V1
1  1
2  2
3  3
```